# Vs2012/Sharepoint2013 throw a weird error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, web, sharepoint-2013

When I debugged an SharePoint 2013 project in VS 2012 on Windows Server 2012, built successful, and when deployed, it throws a weird and unknown error as below.

> Deployment steps appear "Recycling IIS application pool": a task has been canceled.

And I have looked for many information by surfing, but there is no any results I want.

Anybody knows or experiences the error?

Comment: Have you tried running visual studio using "run as administrator" option?

Comment: Have you tried recycling pools using cmd command "iisreset"? Does it work?